# Keep jquery menu open upon click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This appears to be a common problem, but I'm unable to adjust the previously given answers to my situation. I have a jquery vertical accordion menu that I would like to use to navigate two sites, home.html and research.html. Here's how the relevant portion on my home.html looks like:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='research.html'>Research</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='research.html#r1'><span>interests</span></a></li>                      
            <li><a href='research.html#r2'><span>preprints</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='research.html#r3'><span>publications</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='research.html#r4'><span>coauthors</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's how the relevant portion of my research.html looks like:

```
<div id="cssmenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>
    <li class='active'><a href='research.html'>Research</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href='research.html#r1'><span>interests</span></a></li>                      
            <li><a href='research.html#r2'><span>preprints</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='research.html#r3'><span>publications</span></a></li>
            <li><a href='research.html#r4'><span>coauthors</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and here's "my" jquery-code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#cssmenu > ul > li ul').each(function(index, e){
    var count = $(e).find('li').length;
    var content = '<span class="cnt">' + '</span>';
    $(e).closest('li').children('a').append(content);
    });
$('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
    $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
        checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }
    if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    });
```

If I click on Research the sub-menu opens just fine and if I click on a sub-menu entry the corresponding position on the page is loaded. However, the previously open sub-menu is now closed again. How can I avoid this behaviour?

Any help is greatly appreciated, but please keep in mind I'm not a web programmer.

Comment: Can you create a code snippet?

Comment: I will try, never done that.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918843/jquery-accordion-parent-link

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/85ehwyr8/

Comment: Not sure that's helpful...

Comment: Can you please add CSS in jsfiddle so i will have idea

Comment: I did add the CSS code.

Comment: I see now you want to when research page is open then research menu will be expanded by default right?

Answer (score 0):

Please try bellow code 
I have also updated on fiddle

[**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/85ehwyr8/3/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cssmenu > ul > li ul').each(function(index, e) {
    var count = $(e).find('li').length;
    var content = '<span class="cnt">' + '</span>';
    $(e).closest('li').children('a').append(content);
  });
  $('#cssmenu > ul > li > a').click(function() {
    $('#cssmenu li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    if ((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
      $('#cssmenu ul ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
      checkElement.slideDown('normal');
    }
    if ($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });


  var hashTag = window.location.hash;
  if (hashTag != '') {
    $(hashTag).addClass('active');
  }

});
```

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu a {
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 325px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  position: fixed;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Gill Sans;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  color: #005D9A;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a > span {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active {} #cssmenu > ul > li.active > a {
  color: #C80000;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a span {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
#cssmenu span.cnt {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background: none;
}
/* Sub menu */

#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {} #cssmenu ul ul a {
  font-family: Avenir;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  color: #585858;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cssmenu">
  <ul>
    <li class='active'><a href='index.html'>Home</a>

    </li>
    <li id="research"><a href='research.html'>Research</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href='research.html#rarticles'><span>interests</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href='research.html#rarticles'><span>preprints</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href='research.html#rarticles'><span>publications</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href='research.html#rarticles'><span>coauthors</span></a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! From what I can tell you added a identifier variable to the list environment, but this doesn't appear to work (assuming I'm implementing things correctly). If I click on a submenu entry of research the menu is still closed afterwards.